# different types of synhronization methods in linux?

Tags: linux

what are the different types snchronization methods ?(other than semaphore,mutex,binary semaphore)

Comment: Are you talking about concurrency constructs in general, or those provided by Linux...like in the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're talking about application development and not Kernel development.

Linux supports Posix synchronization techniques.  Some common ones are a mutex (for multi-threaded applications) and semaphores.
You can use these in many ways... An example of semaphore usage would be multiple processes and keeping a semaphore in shared memory.

I recommend you do some reading of the following manpages:

[sem_init](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init) 
[pthread_mutex_init](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init)

Also, here's a [good discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472329/how-can-i-synchronize-two-processes-accessing-a-file-on-a-nas) on the usage of file locking

Hope that helps.